# How to modify elements of a Keras Tensor object

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I am building a Convolution Neural Network in Keras that receives batch of images with dimensions (None, 256, 256, 1) and the output would be batches with size (None, 256, 256, 3). Now after the final layer output I want to add a layer that assigns values to some of the pixels in output layer based on a value condition on inputs. Here is what I tried:

**The Function**

```
def SetBoundaries(ins):
    xi = ins[0]
    xo = ins[1]

    bnds = np.where(xi[:, :, :, 0] == 0)
    bnds_s, bnds_i, bnds_j = bnds[0], bnds[1], bnds[2]
    xo[bnds_s, bnds_i, bnds_j, 0] = 0
    xo[bnds_s, bnds_i, bnds_j, 1] = 0
    xo[bnds_s, bnds_i, bnds_j, 2] = 0

    return xo
```

**Keras model**

```
def conv_res(inputs):
    x0 = inputs

    ...

    xc = conv_layer(xc, kernel_size=3, stride=1,
                    num_filters=3, name="Final_Conv")

    # apply assignment function
    xc = Lambda(SetBoundaries, name="assign_boundaries")([x0, xc])
    return xc
```

Finally, the model is built using

```
def build_model(inputs):
    xres = int(inputs.shape[1])
    yres = int(inputs.shape[2])
    cres = int(inputs.shape[3])

    inputs = Input((xres, yres, cres))
    outputs = UNet.conv_res(inputs)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model
```

However, when I run I get the error:

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (assign_boundaries/Equal:0) to a numpy array.
```

Everything works fine without the *Lambda* function. I understand the issue is assigning value to Tensor object but how can I achieve what I am after?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by changing the function to:

```
def SetBoundaries(ins):
    xi = ins[0]
    xo = ins[1]

    xin = tf.broadcast_to(xi, tf.shape(xo))
    mask = K.cast(tf.not_equal(xin, 0), dtype="float32")
    xf = layers.Multiply()([mask, xo])

    return xf
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.where` works with NumPy arrays, but the output from your model is a Tensorflow tensor. Try using [tf.where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where), which is the same thing but for `tf.Tensor`s.